# create new field in output using mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a simple mongodb

```
{
    "name" :"rajesh",
    "age" : 38
},
{
    "name" :"vijay",
    "age" : 27
}
```

I want that in my mongoose output I have like this

```
{
    "name" :"rajesh",
    "age" : 38,
    "temp" : "rajesh_38"
},
{
    "name" :"vijay",
    "age" : 27,
    "temp" : "vijay_27"
}


schema.find(findObj)
    .select({allExistingFields+newField})
```

Please help.

Comment: db.collection.aggregate???

Comment: how to use this in mongoose

Comment: model.aggregate(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with MongoDB using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) / [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html) and [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "temp": {
        $concat: [
          "$name",
          "_",
          {
            $toString: "$age"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can [see it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X41APHrBGeQ)

**Note**: this has a dependency on MongoDB version **4.0** due to the use of `$toString`

You can try doing it with mongoose via:

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "temp": {
        $concat: [
          "$name",
          "_",
          {
            $toString: "$age"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing it the aggregate way is the correct method, but if you are going to use this `temp` field in many of your queries, you might want to consider it making a virtual on you schema like :

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
    name: "String",
    age: "Number"
});

personSchema.virtual('temp').get(() => {
    return `${this.name}_${this.age}`
});
```